# How to use bash to split and unknown number of source file names into specified number of output files

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, sh

I am trying to write a script in BASH that will read all the names of files in a source directory, which has an unknown file count, then split those names as evenly as possible between a specified number of output files. User input is source dir, target dir, and target file count.

For example, lets say we have 10 files in a source directory, and the user specifies they want the names of those files to be split between 3 output files.

SOURCE FILE NAMES:

```
test
test2
test3
test4
test5
test6
test7
test8
test9
```

RESULTING FILES:

```
FILE1
test
test2
test3
test4
```

(has 4)

```
FILE2
test5
test6
test7
```

(has 3)

```
FILE3
test8
test9
test10
```

(has 3)

So far, I have come up with the below, which will always catch all the files because I'm forcing a 'round up', but wont provide the desired number of output files in all cases as it does not account for an uneven number of file names in an output file.

```
ls -l -d -1 $source/{*,.*} | tail -n +3 |  awk '{printf "%s\n",$9}' > hdpLoadList
fileCount=`ls -1 $source | wc -l`
threadCount=$3 

fptf=$(bc <<< "scale=1;($fileCount/$threadCount)+.9")
fptf=${fptf:0:1}

sPos=1
sLen=$fptf
for i in `seq 1 $threadCount`;
 do
   sed -n ${sPos},${sLen}p hdpLoadList | sed -e ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g' > hdpLoadP_$i
   sPos=$(($sPos+$fptf))
   sLen=$(($sLen+$fptf))
 done
```

Comment: how about using `split` command.. for ex if 10 files are input and we need to 3 output files, `split -d -l 3 file_list.txt file` will create 4 files.. detect if extra file was created and append its content to 1st file and delete it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Script, let's say `split`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Create an array with all the files
myArray=("$1"/*)

# Get array length
arrayLength=${#myArray[@]}

# Divide length by the third arg value
divRes=$(( $arrayLength / $3 ))

# Iterate through array using a counter
for ((i=0; i<${#myArray[@]}; i++)); do
    count=$(( $i / $divRes ))
    # Use basename to remove folder path
    echo `basename "${myArray[$i]}"` >> "$2/destFile$count"
done
```

Usage:

```
bash split srcFolder destFolder 3
```

---

Edit: following `Charles Duffy` comment, I've removed the `.sh` extension of the script filename.

Comment: Nice. I might use `${myArray[$i]##*/}` rather than `basename` to avoid paying the cost of a command substitution, though. (I'd also avoid encouraging folks to use `.sh` extensions on bash scripts -- a `.sh` extension encourages folks to run `sh foo.sh`, avoiding the shebang, and means that the script can't be rewritten in an entirely different language without either needing to modify all callers or making its name misleading. We don't run `ls.elf` -- scripts define commands, and commands don't conventionally have extensions on UNIX).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. It works like a charm. I also figured out a way to do this between the post and now, here is the alternate code.  The number 4 will be user input, but in this example is fixed `tTotal=4
tRun=4
while read line
do


echo "$line" >> file_$tRun

tRun=$((tRun-1))

if [[ tRun -lt 1 ]];
then

tRun=$tTotal

fi

done < hdpLoadList`